# NVIDIA driver issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell Inspiron 15 7559.

Specs:

- Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
- 1TB drive
- 16GB memory
- NVidia Geforce GTX 960M

Everything works apart from my nvidia card. I have tried installing many versions which all led to *low graphics mode* error. I recently tried the v384 driver and my system booted up normally and I thought I'd succeeded, but I was wrong. My **Additional Drivers** page shows that I have nvidia 384 selected but **nvidia x server** is empty and system info still shows that I'm running Intel Skylake.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there anything in the UEFI settings (BIOS) for selecting which video hardware to use?

Comment: Ill take a look

Comment: there is nothing in UEFI setting for selecting video hardware

Comment: i have restricted repo enabled :(

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: After many driver installation attempts, you might check the /etc/modprobe.d directory for any files with a blacklist of the nvidia driver you want.  You did run the  sudo apt-get update after enabling the repository didn't you?

Comment: checked the directory, no nvidia drivers blacklisted. yes i did run sudo apt-get update after enabling

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Answer (score -1):

I have finally found the answer on my own.

For those that are experiencing the same issues, you have to install `bumblebee` for optimus support. I used the instructions in [this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nGbWE-pvIE) video, and it worked for me.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-add-repository bumblebee/testing
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367 # or install the newest version if there is a newer one
sudo bumblebee-nvidia bbswitch-dkms prime-indicator
sudo prime-select intel
sudo reboot
```